# Active Directory login

Tags: active-directory

I am new to Mac's.  I have a new MacBook Air OS X 10.9.5. I was given and told to get it on our active directory domain. I was able to figure out how to bind it to AD. I have allow network users to log in at login windows checked. When accessing options, I have allow all network users. 
Directory Utility User Experience, selected create mobile account, selected Use UNC path from Active Directory, Network protocol to be used smb, Administrative, allow administration by checked and allow authenctication from any domain in the forest checked. I have also checked remote login in sharing.  When i log off or restart, I am never prompted with login to login to Active Directory.  Can someone help me.

Thanks in advance 
Mike

Comment: Do you get an "Other" icon at the login window (note that you may have to wait ~30 seconds for it to appear)? Also, what kind of network connection do you have (wired or wireless, and if wireless what security mode)?

Comment: I was connected to both. Once I turned off wireless and rebooted, I was able to login with a network account.  the problem was, I was connecting to the guest netowrk and it was unable to find the domain.  Once I turned off Wi-Fi I was able to log in.  thanks for your help.  Your questions pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gordon Davisson question.  It pointed me in the right direction.
I was connected to both wireless and wired. Once I turned off wireless and rebooted, I was able to login with a network account. the problem was, I was connecting to the guest netowrk and it was unable to find the domain. Once I turned off Wi-Fi I was able to log in

Thank you all,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

In system preferences under users and groups in the login options section did you use the radio button that says "Display login window as Name and password" instead of "list of users"? That will set the login window to require a username and password to log in to the machine as well as active directory.